# Can a C function be used as a selector in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, c, multithreading, selector

I want to start a new thread using a C function, not an objective-C method. I tried

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(func) toTarget: nil withObject: id(data)];
```

where I have

```
void func(void *data) {
   // ...
}
```

and `data` is a `void *`, but I get a runtime crash in `objc_msgSend`, called from

```
-[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]
```

What can I do instead? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Roll your own:

```
// In some .h file.  #import to make the extension methods 'visible' to your code.
@interface NSThread (FunctionExtension)
+(void)detachNewThreadByCallingFunction:(void (*)(void *))function data:(void *)data;
-(id)initWithFunction:(void (*)(void *))function data:(void *)data;
@end

// In some .m file.
@implementation NSThread (FunctionExtension)

+(void)startBackgroundThreadUsingFunction:(id)object
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  void (*startThreadFunction)(void *) = (void (*)(void *))[[object objectForKey:@"function"] pointerValue];
  void *startThreadData               = (void *)          [[object objectForKey:@"data"] pointerValue];

  if(startThreadFunction != NULL) { startThreadFunction(startThreadData); }

  [pool release];
  pool = NULL;
}

+(void)detachNewThreadByCallingFunction:(void (*)(void *))function data:(void *)data
{
  [[[[NSThread alloc] initWithFunction:function data:data] autorelease] start];
}

-(id)initWithFunction:(void (*)(void *))function data:(void *)data
{
  return([self initWithTarget:[NSThread class] selector:@selector(startBackgroundThreadUsingFunction:) object:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSValue valueWithPointer:function], @"function", [NSValue valueWithPointer:data], @"data", NULL]]);
}

@end
```

**NOTE**: I wrote the above code and here by place it in the public domain. (sometimes the lawyers like this kind of stuff)  It is also ***completely untested!***

You can always remove the `NSAutoreleasePool` bits if you can guarantee that the thread entry function also creates one... but it's harmless, has no speed penalty what-so-ever, and makes calling arbitrary C functions that much more simpler.  I'd say just keep it there.

And you can use it like so:

```
void bgThreadFunction(void *data)
{
  NSLog(@"bgThreadFunction STARTING!! Data: %p", data);
}

-(void)someMethod
{
  // init and then start later...
  NSThread *bgThread = [[[NSThread alloc] initWithFunction:bgThreadFunction data:(void *)0xdeadbeef] autorelease];
  // ... assume other code/stuff here.
  [bgThread start];

  // Or, use the all in one convenience method.
  [NSThread detachNewThreadByCallingFunction:bgThreadFunction data:(void *)0xcafebabe];
}
```

When run:

```
2009-08-30 22:21:12.529 test[64146:1303] bgThreadFunction STARTING!! Data: 0xdeadbeef
2009-08-30 22:21:12.529 test[64146:2903] bgThreadFunction STARTING!! Data: 0xcafebabe
```

Comment: There's no much point in doing all this and rolling one's own implementation, while we can haz `dispathc_async_f()`. It's probably better to leave the implementation of threading to Apple's engineers. They maybe know a li'l bit better what's going on in their system.

Comment: Hi tried your code, withInitMethod and this is what I got

-[NSThread initWithFunction:data:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000007b7c0

Answer (score 3):

Create an Objective-C class with a method that simply calls that function. Take the selector of that method and pass it to `NSThread` API.

Comment: OK, yeah, I mean, without doing that. In other words, I want to know if I'm missing some syntax

Comment: I don't think there's a simple syntactical way to do that.  A selector is used to send a message to an object. Sending a message is not identical to simply calling a function. The underlying mechanisms are a bit different.

Comment: I was hoping it would wrap the C function automagically if it had to.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not sure if it's possible, but keep in mind that every Objective-C method has two implicit/hidden arguments, `self` and `_cmd`. An `IMP` is usually `typedef`'d like this:

```
typedef id (*IMP)(id,SEL,...);
```

If you want to jerry-rig methods and selectors, you need to have a method that looks like that:

```
void func (id self, SEL _cmd, void *firstParameter);
```

But even after that, you need to register a selector name with the runtime, then you need to associate that selector with the method, but this is done on a class-by-class basis (i.e. classes can have different implementations of the same selector name), so you at least need to have a dummy class.

It is much, much simpler just to create a dummy class and dummy instance of that class than call the various runtime API just to get `NSThread` to invoke a single C function.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `NSThread` stuff, you can also start a thread with [direct POSIX interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to start a new thread using a C function, not an objective-C method

Then why don't you just use:

1. POSIX threads,
2. GCD?

`dispatch_async_f()` [(man)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async_f.3.html) is suited **exactly for this purpose.**